# Droppable Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

First of all i'm french so sorry if my english is not perfect :/

i want to know if :

```js
$('#drop1').droppable({
    accept: '#drag1',
    if (drop: function()) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
        $('drag1').draggable(disabled)
    } else
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

exist..

(without the if(drop) it work but it stay green thats why i want an "if{}else{})

ty <3

Comment: Please create a working example of the problem

Comment: You cannot just add jquery code in the code snippet and make it work. Either add the required html and complete the snippet or use simple code and add the jquery in there.

Comment: i dont really need a code snippet, i'm just new and i click where i saw code , i dont need any code who works, i just search if it's possible to make an if-else in a drop value :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable/disable droppables by setting the 'disabled' option.

`$('#drop1').droppable('option', 'disabled', true);`

---

Example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gzboYR